# "Invalid expression in guard, case is not allowed in guards" error

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

The following code is deemed an error by `mix`:

```
case test do
      ...
      t when !is_list(t) -> false
      ...
end
```

The error is "Invalid expression in guard, case is not allowed in guards".

However, if I remove the `!`, i.e. write

```
case test do
      ...
      t when is_list(t) -> false
      ...
end
```

no error is reported.

This can't be right? `!` should just be the negation function.

Comment: FWIW, [this](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#!/1) specifically says that `!` is not allowed in a guard clause and [this](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#not/1) specifically says that `not` _is_ allowed in guard clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is not a negation function, it is a macro.

See the code in elixir, `lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex: 1552`,

```
 defmacro !value

  defmacro !{:!, _, [value]} do
    optimize_boolean(
      quote do
        case unquote(value) do
          x when :"Elixir.Kernel".in(x, [false, nil]) -> false
          _ -> true
        end
      end
    )
  end

  defmacro !value do
    optimize_boolean(
      quote do
        case unquote(value) do
          x when :"Elixir.Kernel".in(x, [false, nil]) -> true
          _ -> false
        end
      end
    )
  end
```

The `!` macro expanded is a `case statement`, which is not allowed in elixir guards.

And not is a erlang function:

```
  @spec not true :: false
  @spec not false :: true
  def not value do
    :erlang.not(value)
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it works if you use the keyword `not` instead of `!`.

`Not` is allowed in guard tests, `!` is not allowed in guard tests.

Comment: I see. Why is that the case though. Is there a particular reason to disallow `!`?

Comment: I have no clue why, all I can see is that `!` is a macro (that can receive any argument) and `not` is a function that only accepts booleans and can be inlined by the compiler.